# Magento 2.3 Edit Configuration product added SKU undefined

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, sku

I have added Product and parent products save
When I Edit Configurable products

1. Select Attribute Values and add more parent products
2. Then next Select Skip image uploading at this time
3. Step 4: Summary- Product SKU is Undefined please check Screenshot
   [image]